# A question about conjugacy in Higman's group

Tags: gr.group-theory

In his paper *A finitely generated infinite simple group* (J. London Math. Soc., 1951), Higman introduced the following finitely presented group:

$$
H = \langle x,y,z,w \mid [x,y]=y, \, [y,z]=z, \, [z,w]=w, \, [w,x]=x \rangle .
$$

This group has many remarkable properties, including being acyclic.

Let $H_{x,y} \le H$ be the subgroup generated by $x$ and $y$, and let $H_{z,w}\le H$ be the subgroup generated by $z$ and $w$. Both $H_{x,y}$ and $H_{z,w}$ are isomorphic to the Baumslag--Solitar group $BS(1,2)=\langle a,b \mid aba^{-1}=b^2\rangle$ (although this is not particularly relevant to my question).

> Does there exist a non-trivial element of $H_{x,y}$ which is conjugate in $H$ to an element of $H_{z,w}$?

It would seem to me that the answer is no, but I'm having difficulty proving or disproving it. Probably I am missing some well-known technique for deciding this type of question, which I would be very happy to hear about.

**Motivation**: My co-authors and I are writing about the topological complexity (in the sense of Farber) of aspherical spaces, and the above fact (if it were true) would give a nice example illustrating our techniques.

Comment: I'd say that the usual technique for deciding this sort of question is to find a nice quotient in which the answer is 'obvious'.  Since Higman's group has no finite quotients, and hence very few 'nice' quotients, this technique isn't going to work here.

Comment: I vaguely remember there was some nice lemma in the book of Higman, Scott "Existentially closed groups" that two elements of a group are conjugate if and only if some system of group equations has a solution, and, I can't remember which one, but some of Higman's simple groups was used for that heavily. Sorry I don't have this book -- this is in Chapter 1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, there are no such element. Indeed $H$ is amalgam of the subgroups $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ and $\langle z,w,x\rangle$ over the intersection $\langle x,z\rangle$, which is free (as we see by viewing $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ itself as amalgam of the Baumslag-Solitar $\langle x,y\rangle$ and $\langle y,z\rangle$ over $\langle y\rangle$). [EDIT: my previous argument was mistaken] In an amalgam $A*_CB$, an element of $A$ conjugate to an element of $B$ is actually conjugate to an element of $C$.

Thus an element $u_1$ of $\langle x,y\rangle$ conjugated to an element $u_2$ in $\langle z,w\rangle$ is conjugated to an element in the amalgamated subgroup defining $H$, namely $\langle x,z\rangle$. But we can also view $H$ as an amalgam of $\langle w,x,y\rangle$ and $\langle y,z,w\rangle$ and the argument now implies that $u_1$ is conjugated to an element in $\langle y,w\rangle$.

So some element of $\langle x,z\rangle$ (conjugate to $u_1$) is conjugated to some element in $\langle y,w\rangle$. Using the first amalgam decomposition of $H$ and its Bass-Serre tree, $\langle x,z\rangle$ acts with a fixed vertex. On the other hand, an element of $\langle y,w\rangle$ not conjugated into the cyclic subgroups $\langle y\rangle$ or $\langle w\rangle$ acts hyperbolic. So every element in $\langle y,w\rangle$ conjugate to $u_1$ is conjugate in $\langle y,w\rangle$ to an element in $\langle y\rangle\cup\langle w\rangle$. Again using this argument in the other decomposition of $H$, we get 
that every element in $\langle x,z\rangle$ conjugate to $u_1$ is conjugated in $\langle x,z\rangle$ to an element in $\langle x\rangle\cup\langle z\rangle$.

Since these element exist, we deduce that that some element in $\langle x\rangle\cup\langle z\rangle$ (conjugate to $u_1$) is conjugated to an element in $\langle y\rangle\cup\langle w\rangle$.

By symmetry, we can suppose that some element in $\langle x\rangle$ (conjugate to $u_1$) is conjugate to an element in $\langle y\rangle$.

Now I use that if in an amalgam $A*_CB$ an element of $A$ is conjugate to an element of $C$, then it's conjugate to an element of $C$ by an element of $A$.

Using the first decomposition of $H$, we deduce that some element of $\langle y\rangle$ (conjugate to $u_1$) is conjugate to an element of $\langle x,z\rangle$ by an element of $\langle x,y,z\rangle$, and by the "every" statement above, we can choose the latter element to belong to $\langle x\rangle\cup\langle z\rangle$.

Now in the group $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ (with its explicit presentation with 2 relators), nontrivial powers of $y$ cannot be conjugate to nontrivial powers of $x$ or $z$. Indeed the powers of $x$ survive in the abelianization but not those of $y$ or $z$; on the other hand, nontrivial powers of $y$ are at most exponentially distorted, while $z^{k2^{2^n}}=x^nyx^{-n}z^kx^ny^{-1}x^{-n}$ and thus $z^k$ is partially more than exponentially distorted. So finally the only possibility is $u_1=1$.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! Do you know of a reference for the fact that an element of $A-C$ can't be conjugate to an element of $B-C$ in $A\ast_C B$?

Comment: @Mark it's false actually ($aca^{-1}$ being conjugate to $bcb^{-1}$). What's true is that an element of $A$ conjugate to an element of $B$ is conjugate to an element of $C$. Let me try to fix the answer.

Comment: ... and it's now much more complicated; I hope it's OK...

Comment: Thanks so much for your time. I will try to check the details (and hopefully learn some Bass--Serre theory in the process).

Answer (score 7):

Below is a geometric argument based on the action of Higman's group on its natural CAT(0) square complex. (Of course, Yves' argument is more elementary, but I find this alternative viewpoint enjoyable.)

The key observation is that $H$ can be described as the fundamental group of a square of groups:
$$\begin{array}{ccc} \langle x,y \rangle & \leftarrow \langle y \rangle \rightarrow & \langle y,z \rangle \\ \uparrow & \uparrow & \uparrow \\ \langle x \rangle & \leftarrow \{1\} \rightarrow & \langle z \rangle \\ \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow \\ \langle w,x \rangle & \leftarrow \langle w \rangle \rightarrow & \langle z,w \rangle \end{array}$$
Now, this square of groups is nonpositively curved (as defined by Gersten and Stallings), so it comes from an action of $H$ on some CAT(0) square complex $X$. (Following the construction of the Bass-Serre tree associated to a graph of groups, $X$ can be described directly in terms of cosets of the vertex-, edge-, square-groups of the square of groups.) The action $H \curvearrowright X$ is studied in details in Alexandre Martin's paper *On the cubical geometry of Higman's group*, and there it is proved the following weak acylindricity (see Corollary 2.2, whose proof uses only elementary arguments):

> **Weak acylindricity:** For any two vertices $x,y \in X$ at distance at least three in the $1$-skeleton $X^{(1)}$, the intersection $\mathrm{stab}(x) \cap \mathrm{stab}(y)$ is trivial.

Now, let $\alpha$ be an element of $H$ which belongs to $\langle x,y \rangle$ and which is conjugate to an element of $\langle z,w \rangle$, say $g^{-1}\alpha g \in \langle z,w \rangle$ for some $g \in H$. Consequently, if $A$ (resp. $B$) denotes the vertex of $X$ corresponding to the coset $\langle x,y \rangle$ (resp. $\langle z,w \rangle$), then $\alpha$ belongs to $\mathrm{stab}(A) \cap \mathrm{stab}(gB)$. Two cases may happen:

- Either $d(A,gB) \geq 3$, so that $\mathrm{stab}(A) \cap \mathrm{stab}(gB)=\{1\}$ as a consequence of the weak acylindricity.
- Or $d(A,gB) \leq 2$. In this case, it is not difficult to show that the only possible configuration is that $A$ and $gB$ are two diametrically opposed vertices of some square $C$, hence $$\mathrm{stab}(A) \cap \mathrm{stab}(gB) \subset \mathrm{stab}(C) = \{1\},$$ since square-stabilisers are trivial (this follows from the fact that the square-group of the square of groups defining $H$ is itself trivial).

The conclusion is that $\alpha$ is necessarily trivial.