# Cohomology of simple finite groups remembers the group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

Let $G$ and $H$ be finite simple groups.

> I expect that if $G$ and $H$ are not isomorphic, then their cohomology groups with integral coefficients are not all isomorphic, that is, $H^*(G,\mathbb{Z})$ and $H^*(H,\mathbb{Z})$ are not isomorphic graded abelian groups. Is there any proof of this?

Notice, I do not want to compute those cohomology groups (and as far as I know it hasn't been done yet completely), just to show that they are not allisomorphic.

Comment: Cohomology with which coefficients?

Comment: @YCor thanks, I edited. Of course it's important to consider cohomology with coefficients in a finite field to approach the original problem, I guess.

Comment: With integer coefficients, I guess the cohomology is identically zero... "over a finite field"... a fixed finite field? you should be more precise.

Comment: @YCor There is no finite acyclic group, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291786/acyclic-finite-groups

Comment: @user43326 I explicitly meant the cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbf{Z}$ vanishes, not the homology. Just think that for $G$ simple abelian, $H^1(G,\mathbf{Z})=0$ while $H_1(G,\mathbf{Z})\neq 0$. I know that nontrivial finite groups are not acyclic.

Comment: @YCor Integer cohomology of finite cyclic groups are not zero

Comment: Ah I see... for nontrivial finite cyclic groups $Z/nZ$ we have a central extension $1\to Z\to Z\to Z/nZ\to 1$, so $H^2(Z/nZ,Z)\neq 0$.

Comment: @YCor : more precisely, $H^2(\mathbb{Z/nZ},\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z/nZ}$

Comment: I agree with YCor that you need tro make this question more precise. What exactly does "The cohomology groups with integral coefficients are not isomorphic" mean? for example. It is not reasonable to expect readers to have to spend time figuring out exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Well, the meaning seems clear to me (OP can't certainly be talking about the cohomology group in one particular degree, and wouldn't be implying that the isomorphism should be induced by a map).  In any case I edited the post so that it would be clearer.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for the interest. Of course the isomorphism couldn't be induced by a homomorphism $f:G\to H$ because otherwise it would imply $f$ is an isomorphism (https://www.jstor.org/stable/2042568 - it's about homology groups, actually, but I think the similar argument can be applied). So I just want $H^*(G,\mathbb{Z})\cong H^*(H,\mathbb{Z})$ as user43326 wrote.

Comment: But you'll never reach a precise formulation if you systematically refuse to use quantifiers and refuse to say isomorphism as what. Writing $H^*(G,\mathbf{Z})\cong H^*(G,\mathbf{Z})$ has at least 4 possible meanings since it can mean isomorphic as abelian group, graded abelian group, algebra, graded algebra. Given the previous formulation however, I guess that you mean isomorphism as graded group.

Comment: @YCor let's juct stick with the edit made by user43326, that $H^n(G,\mathbb{Z})\cong H^n(H,\mathbb{Z})$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{Z} _{\geq 0}$ as abelian groups.

Comment: @user43326 It seems to me that you only find the meaning clear because you have rejected a number of possible interpretations that lead to trivial solutions. The meaning of a well  formulated question should be clear without having to do that.

Comment: You're not going to prove a theorem about simple groups without the classification... You can strengthen groups to rings to DGA. Slightly stronger is asking that the group rings be isomorphic. There is a famous example of isomorphic group rings which is not simple, so I doubt a simple example exists (of this stronger case)... I think that you can recover the size of a group from its cohomology (as DGA). So what simple groups have the same size? There is an infinite family of pairs and a sporadic pair. I wouldn't be surprised if one of them has homology iso as groups.

Comment: Given that the integral cohomology groups are difficult to calculate, this is the sort of question that is extremely difficult to counterexample.

Answer (score 8):

This is a remark rather than an answer to your question.  If you remove the word `simple' it is easy to find such pairs of finite groups.  The first examples I learned were (I think) constructed by Atiyah.  Each of the two finite groups has a normal subgroup that is cyclic of order three and quotient dihedral of order 8.  In each case the dihedral group acts non-trivially on the $C_3$, but in one case the kernel of the action is $C_2\times C_2$ whereas in the other case the kernel of the action is $C_4$.  The Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence gives a complete calculation of the integral cohomology ring, and it is just $H^*(C_3)^{C_2}\otimes H^*(D_8)$ in each case.  Somehow cohomology cannot see that the centralizers of the $C_3$ subgroups are different (which is how one can see that the groups are not isomorphic).

I computed the integral cohomology rings of a family of $3$-groups of nilpotence class two in my thesis, and I observed that for each $n\geq 5$ there are a pair of groups of order $3^n$ with isomorphic integral cohomology rings.  I also gave a more conceptual proof that there are pairs of groups of order $p^n$ for each odd $p$ and $n\geq 5$ that are not isomorphic but have isomorphic integral cohomology groups.  My articles are '$3$-groups are not determined by their integral cohomology rings' JPAA Vol 103 (1995) 61-79 and '$p$-groups are not determined by their integral cohomology groups' Bull London Math Soc Vol 27 (1995) 585-589.

None of these arguments are any help for finite simple groups though.