# RIng that is flat over a subring as a right module but not as a left module

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra

What is an example of a ring $R$ and a subring $S \subseteq R$ such that $R$ is flat as a right module but not flat as a left module.

The following question is my motivation:

[Faithful flatness for rings](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403926/faithful-flatness-for-rings)

But please note that I am looking for a more specific counterexample.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take the associative algebra over a field $k$, with generators $x$ and $y$ subject to the relation $xy=0$. This admits a basis consisting of monomials of the form $y^a x^b$. It thus contains a subring $k[x]$, and is flat (even free) over this subring as a right module, on the basis $y^a$, $a\geq 0$. As a left module, it isn't flat, since it isn't even torsion free (for example, $y$ is annihilated by $(x)$).

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot.

Comment: BTW is it possible to produce examples that are torsion-free?

Comment: Sure, it just gets annoying since your subring can't be a PID. I think something like the free associative algebra generated by $x, y, z$ subject to $xy=yx$ and $xz=y$ works (with subring $k[x, y]$) (but this is much larger than my original example and I haven't carefully checked it)

Comment: Why can't it be a PID?

Comment: Torsion-free modules over PIDs are flat

Comment: Yes, of course! I had forgotten. Thanks for reminding me.